# Bind Spring Boot property array to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to bind an array in properties file to an Collection/Array of a object like this:

In application.properties

```
my.application.job[0].name=job-one
my.application.job[0].group=job-group
my.application.job[0].clazz=java.lang.String
my.application.job[1].name=job-two
my.application.job[1].group=job-group
my.application.job[1].clazz=java.lang.Integer
```

In java class

```
@Configuration
public class StartupConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(StartupConfiguration.class);

    private final List<JobProperties> jobs;

    public StartupConfiguration(List<JobProperties> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void applicationStart() {
        try {
            jobs.forEach(LOGGER::info);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.application.job")
public class JobProperties {

    private String name;
    private String group;
    private Class clazz;

}
```

or

```
@Configuration
public class StartupConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(StartupConfiguration.class);

    private final List<JobProperties> jobs;

    public StartupConfiguration(@Value("${my.application.job}") List<JobProperties> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void applicationStart() {
        try {
            jobs.forEach(LOGGER::info);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobProperties {

    private String name;
    private String group;
    private Class clazz;

}
```

The first way I get an List with one object with all properties null, in the second way I get an error on bind properties "Could not resolve placeholder".

I tried to follow some examples, but all of them are using arrays of Integer or String, I did not find an example that helped me.

How can I do that in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following methods (application.properties has no unchanged):

```
@Data
@ToString
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.application")
public class JobConfig {
    List<Job> job;
}

@Data
class Job {
    private String name;
    private String group;
    private String clazz;
}
```

in tests, it can successfully output correct results:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private JobConfig jobConfig;

    @Test
    void contextLoads(){
        System.out.println(jobConfig);
    }

}
```

and result:

```
JobConfig(job=[Job(name=job-one, group=job-group, clazz=java.lang.String), Job(name=job-two, group=job-group, clazz=java.lang.Integer)])
```

**good luck**

Answer (score 0):

your prefix is incorrect, you should set prefix="my.application", as you defined "jobs" in the class, you need to set it as my.application.jobs[0];

as you define the prefix as "my.application.job", then you need to config it like "my.application.job.jobs[0]".

you can ref to below page for the usage of configuration in springboot. even though it is not exactly your case, but i think it can provide some hints.

https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.application.job")
public List<JobProperties> setValues() {
    List<JobProperties> props = new ArrayList<>();
    return props;
}
```